# visual studio 2013 crash on opening xsl

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, visual-studio-2013, crash

Every time I open a .xsl file with Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 it crashes.  I get the error message below.  Pretty useless.  Any suggestions?

I am running VS in the administrator security context (run as).  I do this so I can open and debug on my local IIS 7.5 (instead of the VS debugger / port).

I did install the Azure and SSDT extensions recently (VWDOrVs2013AzurePack.exe and SSDTSetup.exe).  The latter failed to install correctly.

Error below.  Thanks!

Application: devenv.exe
    Framework Version: v4.0.30319
    Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
    Exception Info: System.Security.SecurityException
    Stack:
       at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(System.Object, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, Boolean)
       at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(System.Security.CodeAccessPermission, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)
       at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.VerifyCodeBaseDiscovery(System.String)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetName(Boolean)
       at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetName()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Toolbox.AutoToolboxManagerService.OnAssemblyLoadWorker(System.Reflection.Assembly)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Toolbox.AutoToolboxManagerService+<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0()
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.31101.0, time stamp: 0x54548724
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18839, time stamp: 0x553e88ab
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c42d
Faulting process id: 0x2260
Faulting application start time: 0x01d09ec4b4de9874
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: dc09e38b-0ab8-11e5-9e99-10bf48466a8d
```

Comment: Is that any XSL file, or one in particular? Have you managed to reinstall the bad install since this question was posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this issue.  I renamed the xsl extension to xml.  I worked on the file.  Then I would rename it back to xsl before testing.  I did that for several weeks, maybe a month.

One day I accidentally opened the xsl file before renaming it.  I thought, "oh no! Its going to crash", but it didn't and I haven't experienced the problem since.

If I had to guess, I'd say VS cached something bad.  Overtime, my editing cleared the cache and everything was pink fluffy unicorns dancing on rainbows again.